# How can I replace 0 with the median value in a Pyspark dataframe column?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe called df and have a column "population" in it.
It has 0 value in some of its data. (Its not null its having 0)

I want to replace 0 with median value in pyspark dataframe

I am able to do it using pandas but how can i do it in pyspark dataframe?

Please help

I have done it using pandas but I want to do it in pyspark

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [approx_quantile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile.html) because quantile function gives values like 3754.5 which doesn't seem right for population column.
Here's my example :

```
# Sample dataframe
df.show(10, False)
+-----+----------+
|STATE|POPULATION|
+-----+----------+
|AZ   |923       |
|AZ   |0         |
|AK   |3148      |
|AZ   |0         |
|AZ   |729       |
|AK   |290       |
|AK   |0         |
|AZ   |67146     |
|AK   |1285      |
+-----+----------+

# Build the window function
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
window = Window.partitionBy('state').orderBy('state')

# Add the median column called 'pop_median'
df_aggrted = df.withColumn('POP_MEDIAN', f.expr('approx_percentile(population, 0.5)').over(window))

# Replace with median conditionally
df_updated = df_aggrted.withColumn('POPULATION_MODIFIED', f.when(f.col('POPULATION') == f.lit(0), f.col('POP_MEDIAN'))\
            .otherwise(f.col('POPULATION')))

# Display the new dataframe
df_updated.show(10, False)
+-----+----------+----------+-------------------+
|STATE|POPULATION|POP_MEDIAN|POPULATION_MODIFIED|
+-----+----------+----------+-------------------+
|AK   |290       |290       |290                |
|AK   |0         |290       |290                |
|AK   |1285      |290       |1285               |
|AK   |3148      |290       |3148               |
|AZ   |67146     |729       |67146              |
|AZ   |0         |729       |729                |
|AZ   |729       |729       |729                |
|AZ   |923       |729       |923                |
|AZ   |0         |729       |729                |
+-----+----------+----------+-------------------+
```